# Close Tauri window without closing the entire app

Tags: rust, shutdown, tauri

I use Tauri in my Rust project, but it is not the main component and runs on another thread (on platforms where that is available). Closing the window currently stops the entire app (most of which is command-line based) and I haven't found a way to change this behavior.

I currently have this minimal example:

```rust
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
    println!("Hello after tauri");
}
```

The print after the application never triggers. If you try to move it to a separate thread, the entire application still closes:

```rust
fn main() {
    std::thread::spawn(|| {
        tauri::Builder::default()
            .any_thread()
            .run(tauri::generate_context!())
            .expect("error while running tauri application");
    });
    loop {
        println!("Hello during tauri!");
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loop` wouldn't work, because tauri has its own runtime, so your loop code wouldn't be executed until Tauri's runtime stops.

[image: Tauri architecture]

So depending on what you're trying to do there are several things you can do.

**1. [Not closing](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/system-tray/#preventing-the-app-from-closing) Tauri window:**

Prevent app from exiting:

```rust
tauri::Builder::default()
  .build(tauri::generate_context!())
  .expect("error while building tauri application")
  .run(|_app_handle, event| match event {
    tauri::RunEvent::ExitRequested { api, .. } => {
      api.prevent_exit();
    }
    _ => {}
  });
```

Or just close the window without closing the app (this is how it's done on Mac):

```rust
tauri::Builder::default().on_window_event(|event| match event.event() {
  tauri::WindowEvent::CloseRequested { api, .. } => {
    event.window().hide().unwrap();
    api.prevent_close();
  }
  _ => {}
})
.run(tauri::generate_context!())
.expect("error while running tauri application");
```

**2. Running your loop in parallel in a separate thread:**

```rust
tauri::Builder::default()
            .setup(|app| {
               let handle = app.handle();
               tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async move {
                   loop {
                      println!("Hello during tauri!");
                      // access tauri's app handle here
                      std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
                   }
               });
            })
            .run(tauri::generate_context!())
            .expect("error while running tauri application");
```

**3. Have your logic done in async way:**

If you can keep it simple, running a loop inside a [command](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command/) would be quick and easy.

I would recommend to research on how `async` and Runtimes work in Rust, here's most popular [Tokio's Runtime](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html), since it's mostly what you'll end up with in production.

Comment: "The loop wouldn't work..." well, it does. It just happens to also stop when the Tauri window is closed. Otherwise thanks for your answer, I will look and try (and accept, provided it works) once I get back to the project.

Comment: Hm, depending on the configuration, maybe it would make more sense to run Tauri out of a standalone binary then? And just spawn a child and control it via PID?

for your original question: let me know, if `api.prevent_exit();` works.

Comment: Using the first piece of code you provided works perfectly (at least on Linux, let's hope this pattern carries to other platforms). I haven't tested the other snippets. The first snippet also allows the `Builder` to be `any_thread`, run on another thread and have code run on the main thread (much like in my second snippet in my original question).